# How to apply javascript function to href with specific domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, href

I need to add redirect to other links in my website, I use

```
window.onload = function() {
   var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

   for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
       anchors[i].href = "http://shorter.com/?redirect=" + anchors[i].href
  }
}
```

This will add to all links, but I need to specify only domains to redirect them only like:

```
var domains = ['depositfiles.com', 'rapidshare.com'];
```

**Edit**

for example my page has many links (file.com, depositfiles.com, inda.com).
I need only href with domains in the "domain" variable redirected using my redirector while other is kept the same (direct).

Like for depostitfiles.com
http://shorter.com/?redirect=http://depositfiles.com/

for inda.com
http://inda.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use hostname matching:

```js
var domains = ["google.com", "stackoverflow.com"];

window.onload = function() {
   var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

   for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < domains.length; j++){
        if(anchors[i].hostname === domains[j]){ //domain present
          anchors[i].href = "http://shorter.com/?redirect=" + anchors[i].href
          break;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

*Good point @jonathan-gray - edited*

Comment: indexOf shouldn't be used alone because it can produce unexpected results in these situations. The indexOf checking should be limited to the domain. Extra logic is required to extract the domain from the URL string but a workaround for that may exist.

Comment: it works, but how it can produce unexpected results ?

Comment: If you use it on the link like this: `http://google.com?q=stackoverflow.com` and your domains will contain only `stackoverflow.com` it'll use shorter anyway. Using hostname is a better practice.

Comment: The original post has now been edited but http://website.com/google.com/anything.html would have triggered a redirection.